# VS2010, change path of manifest file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, manifest, filepath

I am having an issue in Visual Studio 2010

When I try to compile a project in release mode, everything works and the window pops up. When  I try to compile it in debug mode I get this error

`Could not write lines to file "\\Debug\\apitest\\test.exe.embed.manifest". The network name cannot be found.`

The real path in my folder structure though is ".\Debug\test.exe.embed.manifest"

How would I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project properties (Build Page) there is the Output Path property.
Check the value there, probably there are too many backslash or some other error.